# Подскажите как работает торрент, как он принимает входящие подключения за роутером?

Tags: windows, ip, torrent

Стоит uTorrent и я задумался, а как же он принимает входящие соединения, там же надо как то пробрасывать порты, но он как то автоматически все настраивает, да и если я просканирую свой внешний IP - я вообще не вижу открытых портов... все закрыто... как так??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB)) все описано.

Клиент не только принимает, но и сам инициирует исходящее соединение на список пиров, полученных от трекера или других пиров. Если все участники обмена (как вы) за NAT'ами, то обмен невозможен.

Comment: аааа, тоесть он просто соединяется? и типа обменивается, а когда за натом находится значит все таки верно ко мне никто сам не коннектиться?

Comment: Да, именно так. За NAT'ом мы не можем принимать, только сами подключаться. Единственное исключение, если нас по DHT найдет другой пир в той же локальной сети.